# Why isnt `d` defined in d3.behavior.drag()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make a circle draggable.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
  drag.on("drag", function(d,i) {
      console.log(d);
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y += d3.event.dy;
      //This will change the center coordinates by the delta
      d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x).attr("y", d.y);
      //This should change the upper left x and y values by the delta
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
          return "translate(" + [ x,y ] + ")"
      })
  })
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/6a6da/31/)

It throws errors for every move on the right red circle, but how come it is saying that `d` is undefined in lines 3, 4, and 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6a6da/33/

The `d,i` arguments would usually refer to bound data, but you're not binding any data. In your case it's sufficient to work with only the event.

```
drag.on("drag", function() {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", +d3.select(this).attr("cx") + d3.event.dx);
  d3.select(this).attr("cy", +d3.select(this).attr("cy") + d3.event.dy);
})l
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6a6da/32/

define `d` as `var d = d3.event;`.

Later on, though, x and y are undefined here: `return "translate(" + [ x,y ] + ")"`. I'm not sure what you want to do there.

Comment: Any idea why this is? All the examples seem to have `d` as the first argument to the handler.

Comment: Not in the docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior ""drag": fired when the element is dragged. d3.event will contain "x" and "y" properties representing the current absolute drag coordinates ..."

Comment: @ Joe: Yeah. The docs are quite vague about what the callback is called with. I wonder why all the examples I can find accept an argument, it *has* to be an earlier version or something. (That's my +1 btw)

Comment: Why the -1? "Not useful" is what the downvote button says, and this is not remotely "not useful."

Comment: See point #2: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast